# Is it grammatical to split a qualifying subclause from the qualified noun?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

While drafting an answer on another site, at one point I came up with the following sentence:

> *You can’t force someone to follow a contract who hasn’t agreed to it.

I think the intended meaning is clear. But if you apply the grammar rules strictly, without regard for semantics, it would seem that the ‘who’ applies to the contract, which is a strange thing to say.

Is this construction grammatical and does it have a distinct name?

Comment: I am not looking for a way to rephrase it, by the way, I already found one.

Comment: The antecedent of "who" can only be a person, so it can only be "someone". **Postposing** of relative clauses like this is not a problem, provided there is no doubt as to what the antecedent is, of course.

Comment: Yes, that's the result of a transformation called [Extraposition from NP](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105786/15299). It's perfectly grammatical; the rule is used, like [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20extraposition), to move heavy clauses and phrases to the end of the sentence, where it's easier to process them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "That" have to be next to the noun it modifies?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/515657/does-that-have-to-be-next-to-the-noun-it-modifies) (essentially, extraposed relative clauses). Some extrapositions sound natural; some sound archaic.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it’s not an unheard of construction, at least.

> We see dimly in the Present what is small and what is great, 
> Slow of faith how weak an arm may turn this iron helm of fate, 
> But the soul is still oracular; amid the market's din, 
> List the ominous stern whisper from the Delphic cave within,— 
> "**They enslave their children's children who make compromise with sin.**"
>
> — James Russell Lowell, [*The Present Crisis*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Present_Crisis)

It’s even less clear here that Lowell meant ‘They {enslave their children’s children} who make compromise with sin.’ and not ‘They enslave {their children’s children who make compromise with sin}.’ (Perhaps he was aiming for some double meaning here.) But it makes sense to think the first interpretation is at least *an* intended one.

I guess if it’s good enough for Lowell, it’s good enough for me.